# En un formulario de inscripción de cursos, ¿Cómo mostrar cuantos días faltan para inscribirse al curso?

Tags: php, mysql

Comunidad, tengo unas dudas sobre fechas en las cuales busco ayuda, resulta que tengo una web app para inscripción de cursos, y en la pagina principal tengo el siguiente código para mostrar un `div`, en donde se ve una foto, nombre del curso, las fechas en las que se va a realizar, las jornadas y un botón para inscribirse,

```html
<?php
    $imagenes[0]='images/cursos/cursoX1.jpg';
    $imagenes[1]='images/cursos/cursoX2.jpg';
    $imagenes[2]='images/cursos/cursoX3.jpg';
    $imagenes[3]='images/cursos/cursoX4.jpg';
    $imagenes[4]='images/cursos/cursoX5.jpg'; 
    $imagenes[5]='images/cursos/cursoX6.jpg'; 
    $imagenes[6]='images/cursos/cursoX7.jpg';   
    $utf8=mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, 
        "SELECT 
  cursos.nombre_curso, 
     cursos.id_curso, 
     GROUP_CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) SEPARATOR ' / ' ) AS Fechas_Cursos, 
     jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
     GROUP_CONCAT( jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada SEPARATOR ' / ' ) AS Tipo_Jornada, 
     cursos.id_relator, 
     cursos.descripcion, 
     cursos.vacantes, 
     cursos.ubicacion
     FROM cursos
     INNER JOIN jornadas_curso ON jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
     AND disponible = 'si'
     AND vacantes >0
     AND fechas_curso > NOW( ) 
     GROUP BY nombre_curso
     ORDER BY fechas_curso ASC");
      if($result)
      {   
   
          while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){  

          $i=rand(0,6);  
   echo"
   <div class='container-fluid proj-bottom'>
   <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8 col-sm-6 fh5co-project animate-box' data-animate-effect='fadeIn' style='margin-left: 300px'>
    
     <a href='#'><img src='$imagenes[$i]' alt='' class='img-responsive'>
      <h3><b>CURSO DISPONIBLE - $registro->nombre_curso</b></h3>
      <h4><b>Fecha de realización:</b> $registro->Fechas_Cursos --
      <b>Jornada(s):</b> $registro->Tipo_Jornada</h4>
     </a>
     <form action='cursos/curso1.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form_curso' target='_self' id='form_curso'>
     <input type='hidden' name='id_curso' id='id_curso' value='$registro->id_curso'>
     <input type='hidden' name='id_relator' id='id_relator' value='$registro->id_relator'>
     <input type='hidden' name='descripcion' id='descripcion' value='$registro->descripcion'>
     <input type='hidden' name='ubicacion' id='ubicacion' value='$registro->ubicacion'>
     <input type='hidden' name='fechas_curso' id='fechas_curso' value='$registro->Fechas_Cursos'>
     <input type='hidden' name='horario_curso' id='horario_curso' value='$registro->horario_curso'>
     <input type='hidden' name='tipo_jornada' id='tipo_jornada' value='$registro->Tipo_Jornada'>
     <input name='nombre_curso' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' type='submit' value='$registro->nombre_curso' id='nombre_curso' /> 
    </form> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

    ";  }
 } ?>
```

Hasta ahí ningún problema, pero ahora me piden no solo la fecha en la que se realizara el curso, sino también cuanto falta para que se realice el curso, ¿Cómo puedo mostrar cuantos días faltan para la realización del curso?

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes hacer una simple diferencia(resta) entre dos fechas algo asi:

```
$fechaActual = date_create("2019-04-12");
$fechaCurso = date_create("2019-05-06");
$diff=date_diff($fechaActual,$fechaCurso);
$months = $diff->format("%m Meses");
$years = $diff->format("%y Años");
$days = $diff->format("%d Dias");

echo 'Faltan: '.$years .' '.$months.' '.$days. ' para el curso!';
```

Resultado:

```
Faltan: 0 Años 0 Meses 24 Días para el curso!
```

como vez primero debo obtener la fecha actual con php, luego hago una diferencia entre la del curso y la actual y tendrás los dias faltantes.

para mas detalle te sugiero la documentación [Diff PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes calcular los días que faltan con diff(), algo así:

```
$fecha1 = new DateTime("2015-02-14");
$fecha2 = new DateTime("2015-02-16");
$diferencia = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
// la salida es 2 días

echo $diferencia->days . ' days ';
```